# Can't get the `data-*-id` attribute to properly record the custom event name via ClickAnalytics plugin

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have a client React app I'm instrumenting in appinsights, and I'm using both the React plugin and the new [ClickAnalytics](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/tree/master/extensions/applicationinsights-clickanalytics-js) plugin. Everything works, telemetry is flowing, however I'm having trouble getting the `data-*-id` custom event feature working properly.

The docs say:

> The id provided in the `data-*-id` will be used as the customEvent name. For example, if the clicked HTML element has the attribute `"data-sample-id"="button1"`, then "button1" will be the customEvent name.

I instrument an element as follows (using [Semantic UI React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/button/)):

```
<Button
  data-custom-id="AddDealButton"
  as={Link}
  color="blue"
  icon
  labelPosition="right"
  size="huge"
>
```

Clicking that button causes the custom event to record but the *name*, "AddDealButton", doesn't flow through. I always get `not_specified` as the event name:

[image: Appinsights screenshot showing not_specified event name]

Reading the docs, there is this warning regarding the plugin configuration:

> If `useDefaultContentNameOrId` is false, then the customEvent name will be "not_specified".

So I am initializing the plugin this way:

```
...
extensions: [reactPlugin, clickPlugin],
extensionConfig: {
  [reactPlugin.identifier]: { history: browserHistory },
  [clickPlugin.identifier]: { autoCapture: true, useDefaultContentNameOrId: true }
}
```

...yet the name does not pass. Am I misconfiguring?  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the problem was in the initialization configuration I showed above. It should be set up as follows:

```
...
extensions: [reactPlugin, clickPlugin],
extensionConfig: {
 [reactPlugin.identifier]: { history: browserHistory },
 [clickPlugin.identifier]: { autoCapture: true, dataTags: { useDefaultContentNameOrId: true } }
}
```

The resulting event name is not being pulled from my `data-custom-id` but rather pulled from the content of the Icon element of the Button component, so the event name becomes "Create new deal", but I can figure that out.

Microsoft's docs show a different samples for the `npm` install method vs the "snippet" method, and so I missed the `dataTags` sample.